# Calculus $2$: Lifting Barbell And Chain Problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

1. A weightlifter holds a $1,300 $N barbell $1$ meter above the ground. One end of a $2$-meter-long chain hangs from the center of the barbell. The chain has a total weight of $600$ N. How much work (in J) is required to lift the barbell to a height of $2$ m?
2. What is the average force (average with respect to height of the barbell from the ground) exerted by the weightlifter in the process?

For number one, I am aware that the formula for this problem is Work = Force x Distance. However, I don't know how this is supposed to be set up. I have previously tried to add the two forces ($1300$ N and $600$ N) together and multiplied it by the distance ($2$ m), but it was wrong. I'm not sure what else could be done here.

As for number two, I am not sure where to go from there, either. All I know is that I have to set up an integral from 0 to 2 with respect to dy and multiply that value by a scale factor of 1/2.

Update: The chain that has not been lifted initially is assumed to still be on the ground. So the higher the barbell is lifted, the more chain that is being lifted from the ground.

Comment: Does the weightlifter allow the chain to go slack as he is lifting up the barbell? For example, is there only 1 meter of the chain hanging when the barbell is initially 1 meter off of the ground?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, the question itself is really ambiguous and badly worded imo. But I'm curious to know how that affects the calculations.

Comment: I agree. I'm getting an answer of 1450J, assuming the weightlifter can allow the chain to go slack as it is being lifted. Is that the answer you have?

Comment: I didn't get that answer, unfortunately. I'm just not sure what the logic is that leads to that answer. If you could explain that to me, that would help immensely.

Comment: Hint: Model the chain as a spring where $k=300$ newtons per meter.

Comment: Is the answer to the first one $1750N$? The second one looks to be more involved, I'll try it later if my answer to the first is correct

Comment: Hey, can you explain your thought process that led you to get 1750 N? I don't have an answer key for this question, so I can't verify if it is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the weight$-$lifter is located at a point $2$ meters above the ground, is pulling the barbell up to his position, and can allow the part of the chain he has already lifted to go slack.

With this interpretation, we see that, initially, there is $1$ meter of chain hanging with the $1300N$ barbell attached at the other end; the weight$-$lifter need only lift $1$ meter of the chain up to his position along with the $1300N$ barbell.

Consider when the weight$-$lifter has lifted $y$ meters of the chain up to his position, where $0\leq y\leq 1$.

This means there is $1-y$ meters of chain left hanging which weighs $300(1-y)N$ along with the $1300N$ barbell.

The amount of work required to lift the chain an additional $dy$ meters is around $$dW=[300(1-y)+1300]dy$$

Therefore $$W=\int_{y=0}^{y=1}[300(1-y)+1300]dy=1450$$

is the total amount of work required.

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting. Unfortunately, 1450 J wasn't the correct answer either, so I asked my professor for clarification of the question. When the barbell is to be lifted up by 1 meter, it is to be assumed that the remaining chain is left on the ground. As the lifter lifts the barbell, more chain is being lifted off the ground in the process.

Comment: The $300(1-y)$ should be $300(1+y)$ as $1+y$ meters of the chain are in the air when the barbell is at height $y$ above the start.  That will make the answer $1750$ J  The other $2-y$ meters of the chain are still on the ground.